# How can I refactor this to use Monad transformers and for comprehensions?

Tags: scala, monad-transformers, scala-cats

How can I refactor this code to use cats EitherT, ReaderT(?) and Future, so I can get rid of the nesting and write it in a for-comprehension style?

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

trait Foo[A, B, C, D, E] {

  def bar(f: A => Future[B]): Future[B]

  def baz: Future[Either[E, Future[C]]]

  def qux(f: C => B)(a: A): B

  def quz(e: E): Future[B]

  def corge(c: C): B

  def quux: Future[B] =
    bar { a =>
      baz flatMap {
        case Left(e) => quz(e)
        case Right(x) => x map { _ =>
          qux(c => corge(c))(a)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need monad transformers most probably. Redesign `Future[Either[E, Future[C]]]` to `Future[Either[E, C]]` and you can do everything in one `for-comprehension`

Comment: Future already embeds a `Try` as a notion of `Failure`, so what you are doing is in effect foo bar code, I'm not sure using `Either[Exception, B]]` is in any way meaningful at all. Assuming you mean to represent the failure type of a future as something else than `scala.util.Failure`, you should never ever end up with a signature like that, it's just a smell, so stick to `Future[Either[A, B]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The presence of a `case Left(e) => quz(e)` in your expression shows that you are not using your `Future[Either[E, Future[C]]]` as a `Monad[L => Future[Either[E, Future[L]]]]`; Monad transformers won't be of any help here.